# Como limitar a quantidade de itens que aparece por pagina em uma tabela no angular

Tags: javascript, angular

fiz essa funcao para pegar a quantidade de objetos que tem no meu array, beleza funcionou, mas na minha tela ainda aparece a quantidade total e eu só quero que apareca 10 por pagina:

````
      for (const obj of this.rows) {
        if (obj.id === '0')this.counter++;
        
      }
      console.log(this.counter)```
````

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Existe várias formas dependendo de como está fazendo, pode ser feito pelo *back-end* mandando paginado, pode ser pelo **front** com vc devolvendo pra view a quantidade de registros, pode usar um plugin de tabela que já fiz isso pra vc. Tem várias formas!

Answer (score -1):

Você pode limitar sua coleção pra mostrar até 10 registros, exemplo com 3:

```
 this.lista = [
    {"id": 1, "valor":"ABC1"},
    {"id": 2, "valor":"ABC2"},
    {"id": 3, "valor":"ABC3"},
    {"id": 4, "valor":"ABC4"},
    {"id": 5, "valor":"ABC5"}
  ];
    
    let limit = 3;
    
    this.lista.slice(0, limit);
```

A lista irá retornar 3 registros.

Depois é só usar o for:

```
*ngFor="let item of lista"
```